# WF4 Rehosted Designer

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflow-rehosting

At design time，Can I dynamically change the root activiti's variables  by code?
Like this：

```
(Designer.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>().Root.GetCurrentValue() as RootActivity).Variables.Add(new Variable<bool>("a",false));
```

Give me some advice.Thanks

Comment: Well, what happens if you try executing the code snippet you provided?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't cast the `ModelItem` value. Changes at runtime must **always** be applied to the `ModelItem` itself.

This is the equivalent to your code but changing the ModelItem instead. Not tested.

```
var modelItem = Designer.Context.Services.GetService<ModelService>().Root;

modelItem.Value.Properties["Variables"].Collection.Add(new Variable<bool>("a",false));
```